# How to handle concurrency in API?

Tags: java, rest, concurrency

Context:
I have a storage/DB where I store a `<String, List<Integer>> -> <uniqueName, numbersPresentForTheName>` mapping each time:

I am writing an API that does the following:

Comment: What does « t = … » mean?

Answer (score 0):

If your two calls are on separate threads, and the steps of the two calls are interleaved over time, then you are seeing correct behavior.

If both threads retrieved a set of three values, and both threads replaced the existing set in storage with a new set of four values, then whichever thread saves their set last wins.

The key idea here to understand is *atomic actions*. The retrieval of the data and the update of the data in your system are separate actions. To achieve your aim, you must combine those actions two actions into one. This combining is the purpose of [transactions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) and [locks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking) in databases.

See also the correct [Answer by VoiceOfUnreason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65314544/642706) along the same line.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we make sure this does not happen?

The usual answer is that you use a compare-and-update operation, rather than just an update operation.

```
t = 1 -> call readStorage 

t = 10  -> get response from readStorage <ABCD, [1,2,3]>

t = 11 -> comapreAndUpdateStorage ABCD, [1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,4]
```

```
t = 5 -> Request 1 to the API: <ABCD, [5]>

t = 6 -> call readStorage 

t = 11 -> get response from readStorage <ABCD, [1,2,3]>  (note that we didn't get 4 as first call didnt update 4 yet)

t = 13 -> compareAnUpdateStorage ABCD, [1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,5] (This call will fail, because the current value is [1,2,3,4])
```

In other words, we're trying to address the lost edit problem by ensuring that the first edit always wins.

That's the first piece; the rest of the work is choosing an appropriate retry strategy.